# Workflow for using Plastic SCM with public code hosting services

Tags: import, github, export, bitbucket, plasticscm

Is there a straightforward workflow to use Plastic SCM in-house while using one of the popular code hosting services like github or Bitbucket preferrably without requiring "double bookkeeping"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As VonC pointed, there's no straightforward way to do it right now with 3.0 (unless you do a "little bit" of scripting) but we're working on it as one of the core features in the upcoming 4.0.

Today, the internal 4.0 release (find [some screenshots here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/plasticscm/sets/72157626193903187/)) is able to do synchronization using fast-export/fast-import. For instance:

- fast-export from git (saving the export marks)
- fast-import into Plastic SCM (generate your own import-marks to be reused)
- do changes in Plastic 4.0
- fast-export to Git from Plastic

And so on.

The limitation, of course, is that using this approach you can't handle concurrent changes made at both sides.

That's why we're working on a real "bi-directional synch".

Plastic 4.0 will be a major change since we move from our "dynamic dag" into a static one (like Git), which will make communication a lot easier.

We're already using it internally for Plastic development (moved a few weeks ago from 3.0 to 4.0), but it is still under testing, development and so on.

Watch the new screenshots of the [Distributed Branch Explorer](http://www.flickr.com/photos/plasticscm/5585831445/in/set-72157626193903187), one of the great enhancements to unveil what's behind the evolved core...

Comment: Excellent, I was hoping you would see this question. +1.

Comment: We're moving forward on providing a better interop: http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2012/04/using-plastic-scm-as-github-client.html

Comment: Well, we actually improved a little bit (quite a lot! :P) how to interop with other SCMs, specially git. Take a look at GitSync: basically you can turn Plastic into a Git client: http://www.plasticscm.com/gitsync/index.html

Answer (score 3):

They might not be a "straightforward" workflow yet, in term of round-trip conversion between a Plastic SCM repo and a Git repo.
See the answer from **[pablo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/72456/pablo)** in [this thread](http://www.plasticscm.net/forum193/default.aspx?g=posts&t=211):

> > > Intrigued enough about Plastic to try and evaluate it, but would want to start off by importing some git projects (some of mine, some bigger projects checked out from github)
> >
> > > So - is there a way to import a git repository, complete with all commits, branches, tags, etc?
>
> Right now the best way would be to move from git into svn and then import from there.
>
> Our plan is to have a bi-directional synchronization with Git in a few months, but it is not yet there so since you want to start using Plastic now I'd better go for a svn import or simply importing a working copy...

That doesn't mean you cannot use a DVCS repo right within your Plastic SCM workspace, but unless you do a strict "double bookkeeping" (that you don't want), you will only commit in the DVCS (Git or Mercurial) repo only the significant commits/changesets you want to push back to a GitHub/bitbucket.

Comment: Not exactly the answer I wanted to hear :) but thanks a lot for the help! Maybe their bi-directional synchronization with git will be done soon.

Comment: @Alexander: if pablo sees this question, he will be able to provide a more definitive answer.